# How can I rewrite this url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

This is my login script. I am redirecting the user to `/sws/index.php?user=$user` but I want to use `.htaccess` to redirect them to `/sws/index/user/$user`.

The `$user` variable represents the users username!

I have tried lots of different tutorials to try and rewrite the URL but they didn't work! Can anyone suggest a `.htaccess` script that would work here?
Also, when the user logs in I want the URL to be rewritten automatically.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    include "functions/password.php";

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users0 WHERE email='$email'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);

    if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
        session_start();

        $_SESSION["id"] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION["first_name"] = $row['first_name'];
        $_SESSION["last_name"] = $row['last_name'];
        $_SESSION["email"] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION["company"] = $row['company'];
        $user = $_SESSION['first_name'] . $_SESSION['last_name'];

        header('Location: index.php?user=' . $user);
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php?error');
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
RewriteRule ^index/user/(.*)$ index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The below Apache redirect will do this (Even the URL has some more arguments also e-g: index.php?user=thanga&arg1=test).

```
RewriteRule ^index.php\?user\=([A-Za-z_0-9]*)(.*)$ index/user/$1$2 [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am redirecting the user to `/sws/index.php?user=$user` but I want to use `.htaccess` to redirect them to `/sws/index/user/$user`.

This isn't something you should be doing in `.htaccess`. Your application should redirect them to `/sws/index/user/$user` and you then use .htaccess (mod_rewrite) to *internally rewrite* the request to `/sws/index.php?user=$user` (the real URL). (If you do it in .htaccess then the user will experience multiple/unnecessary redirects.)

The only time you would need to do this in .htaccess is if the URL had previously been indexed by search engines or linked to. But since this is part of your login script then it's *probably not necessary*. (?)

So, change your script redirect to:

```
header('Location: /sws/index/user/'.$user);
```

Then, in the `.htaccess` in the document root, *rewrite* the request back to the full URL (similar to what devpro has already posted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sws/index/user/(.*)$ sws/index.php?user=$1 [L]
```